# Why didn't the zombies eat her initially?

Tags: plot-explanation, warm-bodies

After R eats Perry's brains, he falls for Julie.  He then takes her back to the airport, and she was in the group of zombies that went back to the airport.  Why didn't the other zombies attack and eat her?

Comment: Gonna be "that guy" and say "Cause then there'd be no movie?".  But honestly, this bugged me, too.

Comment: Maybe she didn't have any brains worth eating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other zombies didn't eat Julie because R put some of his blood on her which covered up her scent.  He repeats this at least one other time to protect her.

Comment: +1 When Julie runs out of the airplane to escape and the other zombies smell her and run toward her, R repeats this and puts zombie blood on her to cover her scent. He tells her to act dead, so she over-emotes and R says "too... much" and she tones it down a bit.